# HP computer wont boot from bootable DVD and CD

Tags: hard-drive, boot, laptop, windows-8.1

My notebook is one HP 1000 Notebook having windows 8.1 installed.
Last night I was trying to split the partition C and add some spaces to partition D. So i was using `PartitionWizard` to do it but it couldn't split `C` so I tried `Disk Management` **Shrink volume** option to split `C`. Then I used `Partition Wizard` to move the system drive for `HP Recovery` (a hidden drive about 300 MB capacity) behind the free space in order to join the space to `D`. after that I restart and now nothing is working fine...
I can't reboot the computer to any DVD or CD. (The option in BIOS is set to boot from CD first)
can you help me how to force the computer to boot from the DVD? (windows 7 installation DVD)

Comment: How confident are you about the integrity of the disk? Did you burn it yourself? Also, reordering partitions is usually a bad idea. XD

Comment: @MetaNova: If you are talking about the DVD I burn, I should say that I tried with some other disks too, but nothing happened... 
and about reordering, yes I know... but how else could I join the space with `D`?
the problem, now, is that why I can't reboot to any other disk... Is it managed by windows 8.1?

Comment: No, your ability to boot disk media should not be affected by Windows. I'd try using the boot options/boot device/equivalent option to directly select the CD drive to ensure your system is attempting to boot from it.